# can't save specific td text in jquery variable

Tags: jquery

Having a problem getting var longlat stored.  In this example I want var longlat = 40.0989, -83.1615, but I keep getting an empty string in the console.

```
<table id="datatable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="83">
            <td><span class="label label-primary dtMap">Map</span></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td class="latlong">40.0989, -83.1615</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
        ... more entries similar to the above
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#datatable').on('click', '.dtMap', function () {

    var data = {'activity_id': $(this).parents('tr').attr('id')};

    var latlong = $(this).find('.latlong').text();
    console.log(latlong);

    ... some more stuff below 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
var latlong = $(this).parent().siblings('.latlong').text();
```

since `.latlong` is the sibling of parent `td` of clicked `.dtMap` span.

---

You can also use `.closest()`:

```
var latlong = $(this).closest('tr').find('.latlong').text();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XF4DT/)**

Comment: hmm... this makes sense to me... go to the tr then the td of .latlong, but it is returning a TypeError: $(...).parent.siblings is not a function.

Comment: Please make sure that you've included jQuery. Also check my update and working demo.

Comment: Yes, I have jquery included haha. Using closest() seemed to do the trick for some reason.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
var latlong = $(this).parent().find('.latlong').html();
```

Comment: Getting undefined in the console... there is definitely a value there in the table.